# Python: Using locals() to print dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting, syntactic-sugar

One of the nicest tools in Python is `locals()` in string formatting:

```
>>> st="asdasd"
>>> print "%(st)s" % locals()
asdasd
```

However, this can't be done with dictionary values:

```
>>> d={1:2, 3:4}
>>> print "%(d[1])s" % locals()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'd[1]'
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the syntactic sugar analogy with `locals`. Care to clarify?

Comment: how about `"%(key)s" % d`? Note that only string keys can be used in this way.

Comment: Eli, it is a syntactic sugar, because `print "name: %s" % user_name` is less readable, but equivalent, to `print "name: %(user_name)s" % locals()`, especially in long strings. It also helps avoid confusion in argument order for lists, e.g. `print "first_name:%s, last_name:%s, city:%s" % (last_name, first_name, city)"` where the bug is less obvious.

Comment: I think most python programmers would totally disagree with your example. You just seem to misunderstand what string formatting does. Also I wouldn't call this "syntactic sugar".

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel, Care to elaborate? according to Wikipedia, Syntactic sugar is "...designed to make things easier to read or to express, while alternative ways of expressing them exist." I think this is a good example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> d={1:2, 3:4}
>>> print '{0[1]}'.format(d)
2
>>> print '{0[d][1]}'.format(locals())
2
>>> print '{[d][1]}'.format(locals())
2
>>>
```

the last one only works with 2.7